# selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable trying sending keys

Tags: python, selenium

trying to input text in email area in https://www.mobile.ir/users/account/login.aspx but i get error
i tried using webdriverwait but it didnt worked
thanks for advance
hear's my code:

```
import time
import datetime
import random
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

ch_options=Options()
ch_options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=chrome-data")
chrome=webdriver.Chrome(options=ch_options,executable_path="/Users/LENOVO/Desktop/chromedriver.exe")
ch_options.add_argument("user-data-dir=chrome-data")
chrome.get("https://www.mobile.ir/users/account/login.aspx")
chrome.find_element_by_name("email").send_keys("myemail")
```

and i get this error:

```
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\mobile.ir\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\LENOVO\PycharmProjects\mobile.ir\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable
  (Session info: chrome=83.0.4103.116)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try finding the element with its full xpath. I had a similar issue where I had to click on an element which has a property javascript onclick function. the full xpath method worked and no interactable exception was thrown.

Looking at the site, I think this may be the path for the e-mail:

```
//*[@id="login_email"]
```

The full xpath being:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/form/div[3]/input
```

Hope this helps!!